# Redirect all urls that contain /content/ to home page using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lamp

I want to redirect all urls which has www.example.com/content/xyz... to home www.example.com

The condition here is to check, if the request contains /content/ then only I need to redirect it to root level domain.

The site is hosted on Linux Server, and build using wordpress.

How can I do this using htaccess rewrite rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/content.*$
RewriteRule .*  /     [L,R=301,DPI]
```

Comment: I was totally wrong about the Page Not found error. It is pretty obvious that I was somewhat dense when answering the question. Krunal sorry for confusing you. I've removed my answer just to stop messing things.

Comment: not to worry... however you tried it, and corrected it that's great thing... thank you